# ng-admin Client Side Search Filter

Tags: angular, filter, ng-admin

Is there a way to implement a client side search filter?

```
.filters([
  nga.field('q', 'template')
    .label('')
    .pinned(true)
    .template('<div class="input-group"><input type="text" ng-model="value" placeholder="Search" class="form-control"></input><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span></div>'),
])
```

But the problem is that the client sends a request everytime I change the value in the input field. Is there a way that the filter is used clientside only? I did not find anything in the documentation.